# Recursivity XML SQL OPENXML

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, openxml, xquery-sql

I can't found how to do that...
I want to get the properties "fullName" and "passed" of all test-suite and test-case of this XML code. This XML returns the result of unit tests. I want to store them in a simple table with columns: FullName, Passed.
Do you've got any idea of how to do that?

I've already seen OPENXML and XQuery. I chose OPENXML, but I can change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<test-run id="2" name="ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll" fullname="C:/Dev/ITest-Runner-develop/Tests/Solutions/ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore/ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.820095" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103" random-seed="670441718">
  <command-line><![CDATA[C:\Dev\ITest-Runner-develop\Tests\Solutions\ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore\ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll --wait]]></command-line>
  <filter />
  <test-suite type="Assembly" id="1027" name="ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll" fullname="C:/Dev/ITest-Runner-develop/Tests/Solutions/ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore/ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.820095" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103">
    <environment framework-version="3.10.1.0" clr-version="4.0.30319.42000" os-version="Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134 " platform="Win32NT" cwd="C:\Dev\ITest-Runner-develop\Tests\Solutions\ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore\ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1" machine-name="DESKTOP-FG6JQ9B" user="Alexandre Spitz" user-domain="DESKTOP-FG6JQ9B" culture="fr-FR" uiculture="fr-FR" os-architecture="x64" />
    <settings>
      <setting name="WorkDirectory" value="C:\Dev\ITest-Runner-develop\Tests\Solutions\ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore\ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1" />
      <setting name="NumberOfTestWorkers" value="8" />
    </settings>
    <properties>
      <property name="_PID" value="24300" />
      <property name="_APPDOMAIN" value="ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests" />
    </properties>
    <test-suite type="TestSuite" id="1028" name="ITI" fullname="ITI" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.803916" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103">
      <test-suite type="TestSuite" id="1029" name="PrimarySchool" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.803092" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103">
        <test-suite type="TestSuite" id="1030" name="Tests" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.803066" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103">
          <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="1000" name="PublicModelChecker" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="2" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" duration="0.115123" total="2" passed="1" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="0">
            <test-case id="1002" name="public_API_is_not_modified" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker.public_API_is_not_modified" methodname="public_API_is_not_modified" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker" runstate="Runnable" seed="1443745743" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" duration="0.097641" asserts="0" />
            <test-case id="1001" name="write_current_public_API_to_console_with_double_quotes" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker.write_current_public_API_to_console_with_double_quotes" methodname="write_current_public_API_to_console_with_double_quotes" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker" runstate="Explicit" seed="571978764" result="Skipped" label="Explicit" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" duration="0.001319" asserts="0" />
          </test-suite>
          <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="1003" name="T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="12" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.587160" total="12" passed="12" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="43">
            <test-case id="1004" name="t1_creating_named_schools" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t1_creating_named_schools" methodname="t1_creating_named_schools" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="994560064" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.159002" asserts="5" />
            <test-case id="1005" name="t2_classrooms_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t2_classrooms_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" methodname="t2_classrooms_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="136635326" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.094843" asserts="9" />
            <test-case id="1006" name="t3_teachers_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t3_teachers_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" methodname="t3_teachers_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1831059769" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.087888" asserts="10" />
            <test-case id="1007" name="t4_pupils_are_created_by_classrooms_and_have_a_unique_firstname_and_lastname" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t4_pupils_are_created_by_classrooms_and_have_a_unique_firstname_and_lastname" methodname="t4_pupils_are_created_by_classrooms_and_have_a_unique_firstname_and_lastname" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="726505736" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.051030" asserts="11" />
            <test-suite type="ParameterizedMethod" id="1016" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="8" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.193696" total="8" passed="8" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="8">
              <test-case id="1008" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(null,null)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(null,null)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="755760840" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.022325" asserts="1" />
              <test-case id="1009" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1801082774" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.021001" asserts="1" />
              <test-case id="1010" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Y&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Y&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="354333195" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.020189" asserts="1" />
              <test-case id="1011" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,null)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,null)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1986354125" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.021026" asserts="1" />
              <test-case id="1012" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,&quot;&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,&quot;&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1406049006" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.027154" asserts="1" />
              <test-case id="1013" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,&quot;A&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,&quot;A&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1296832878" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.022154" asserts="1" />
              <test-case id="1014" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(null,&quot;Valid&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(null,&quot;Valid&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1460153577" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.034753" asserts="1" />
              <test-case id="1015" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;B&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;B&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="2096275179" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.024422" asserts="1" />
            </test-suite>
          </test-suite>
          <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="1017" name="T2SchoolObjectsNaming" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="4" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.045095" total="4" passed="4" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="41">
            <test-case id="1018" name="t1_teachers_can_be_found_by_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming.t1_teachers_can_be_found_by_name" methodname="t1_teachers_can_be_found_by_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" seed="1569413628" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.016131" asserts="11" />
            <test-case id="1019" name="t2_pupils_can_be_found_by_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming.t2_pupils_can_be_found_by_name" methodname="t2_pupils_can_be_found_by_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" seed="1146943241" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.003300" asserts="11" />
            <test-case id="1020" name="t3_classrooms_can_be_found_by_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming.t3_classrooms_can_be_found_by_name" methodname="t3_classrooms_can_be_found_by_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" seed="1350320885" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.001308" asserts="11" />
            <test-case id="1021" name="t4_classrooms_can_be_renamed" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming.t4_classrooms_can_be_renamed" methodname="t4_classrooms_can_be_renamed" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" seed="2075361146" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.024041" asserts="8" />
          </test-suite>
          <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="1022" name="T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="4" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.045094" total="4" passed="4" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="19">
            <test-case id="1023" name="t1_teachers_can_be_assigned_to_a_classroom" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation.t1_teachers_can_be_assigned_to_a_classroom" methodname="t1_teachers_can_be_assigned_to_a_classroom" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" seed="1473089842" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.000702" asserts="5" />
            <test-case id="1024" name="t2_when_a_teacher_is_assigned_to_a_classroom_he_losts_its_previous_classroom" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation.t2_when_a_teacher_is_assigned_to_a_classroom_he_losts_its_previous_classroom" methodname="t2_when_a_teacher_is_assigned_to_a_classroom_he_losts_its_previous_classroom" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" seed="329699032" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.000359" asserts="6" />
            <test-case id="1025" name="t3_teachers_and_classrooms_must_belong_to_the_same_school" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation.t3_teachers_and_classrooms_must_belong_to_the_same_school" methodname="t3_teachers_and_classrooms_must_belong_to_the_same_school" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" seed="556737192" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.043239" asserts="3" />
            <test-case id="1026" name="t4_assigning_a_teacher_to_a_null_classroom_removes_its_assignment" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation.t4_assigning_a_teacher_to_a_null_classroom_removes_its_assignment" methodname="t4_assigning_a_teacher_to_a_null_classroom_removes_its_assignment" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" seed="967137718" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.000626" asserts="5" />
          </test-suite>
        </test-suite>
      </test-suite>
    </test-suite>
  </test-suite>
</test-run>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FROM OPENXML` is outdated and should not be used any more.

If I get this correctly you are looking for any occurance of attributes "fullname" or "passed". the following will not look at the position. No recursion needed, just `XQuery`:

```
    DECLARE @xml XML=
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <test-run id="2" name="ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll" fullname="C:/Dev/ITest-Runner-develop/Tests/Solutions/ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore/ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.820095" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103" random-seed="670441718">
      <command-line><![CDATA[C:\Dev\ITest-Runner-develop\Tests\Solutions\ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore\ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1\ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll --wait]]></command-line>
      <filter />
      <test-suite type="Assembly" id="1027" name="ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll" fullname="C:/Dev/ITest-Runner-develop/Tests/Solutions/ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore/ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests.dll" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.820095" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103">
        <environment framework-version="3.10.1.0" clr-version="4.0.30319.42000" os-version="Microsoft Windows 10.0.17134 " platform="Win32NT" cwd="C:\Dev\ITest-Runner-develop\Tests\Solutions\ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore\ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1" machine-name="DESKTOP-FG6JQ9B" user="Alexandre Spitz" user-domain="DESKTOP-FG6JQ9B" culture="fr-FR" uiculture="fr-FR" os-architecture="x64" />
        <settings>
          <setting name="WorkDirectory" value="C:\Dev\ITest-Runner-develop\Tests\Solutions\ITI-PrimarySchool-NetCore\ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.1" />
          <setting name="NumberOfTestWorkers" value="8" />
        </settings>
        <properties>
          <property name="_PID" value="24300" />
          <property name="_APPDOMAIN" value="ITI.PrimarySchool-NetCore.Tests" />
        </properties>
        <test-suite type="TestSuite" id="1028" name="ITI" fullname="ITI" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.803916" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103">
          <test-suite type="TestSuite" id="1029" name="PrimarySchool" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.803092" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103">
            <test-suite type="TestSuite" id="1030" name="Tests" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="22" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.803066" total="22" passed="21" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="103">
              <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="1000" name="PublicModelChecker" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="2" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" duration="0.115123" total="2" passed="1" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="1" asserts="0">
                <test-case id="1002" name="public_API_is_not_modified" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker.public_API_is_not_modified" methodname="public_API_is_not_modified" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker" runstate="Runnable" seed="1443745743" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" duration="0.097641" asserts="0" />
                <test-case id="1001" name="write_current_public_API_to_console_with_double_quotes" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker.write_current_public_API_to_console_with_double_quotes" methodname="write_current_public_API_to_console_with_double_quotes" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.PublicModelChecker" runstate="Explicit" seed="571978764" result="Skipped" label="Explicit" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" duration="0.001319" asserts="0" />
              </test-suite>
              <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="1003" name="T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="12" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.587160" total="12" passed="12" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="43">
                <test-case id="1004" name="t1_creating_named_schools" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t1_creating_named_schools" methodname="t1_creating_named_schools" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="994560064" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:10Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="11.159002" asserts="5" />
                <test-case id="1005" name="t2_classrooms_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t2_classrooms_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" methodname="t2_classrooms_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="136635326" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.094843" asserts="9" />
                <test-case id="1006" name="t3_teachers_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t3_teachers_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" methodname="t3_teachers_are_created_by_school_and_have_a_unique_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1831059769" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.087888" asserts="10" />
                <test-case id="1007" name="t4_pupils_are_created_by_classrooms_and_have_a_unique_firstname_and_lastname" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t4_pupils_are_created_by_classrooms_and_have_a_unique_firstname_and_lastname" methodname="t4_pupils_are_created_by_classrooms_and_have_a_unique_firstname_and_lastname" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="726505736" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.051030" asserts="11" />
                <test-suite type="ParameterizedMethod" id="1016" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="8" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.193696" total="8" passed="8" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="8">
                  <test-case id="1008" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(null,null)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(null,null)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="755760840" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.022325" asserts="1" />
                  <test-case id="1009" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1801082774" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.021001" asserts="1" />
                  <test-case id="1010" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Y&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Y&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="354333195" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.020189" asserts="1" />
                  <test-case id="1011" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,null)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,null)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1986354125" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.021026" asserts="1" />
                  <test-case id="1012" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,&quot;&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,&quot;&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1406049006" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.027154" asserts="1" />
                  <test-case id="1013" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,&quot;A&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;Valid&quot;,&quot;A&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1296832878" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.022154" asserts="1" />
                  <test-case id="1014" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(null,&quot;Valid&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(null,&quot;Valid&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="1460153577" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.034753" asserts="1" />
                  <test-case id="1015" name="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;B&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle.t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters(&quot;B&quot;,&quot;Valid&quot;)" methodname="t5_pupils_firstname_and_lastname_must_be_not_null_and_longer_than_2_characters" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T1SchoolObjectsLifeCycle" runstate="Runnable" seed="2096275179" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.024422" asserts="1" />
                </test-suite>
              </test-suite>
              <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="1017" name="T2SchoolObjectsNaming" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="4" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.045095" total="4" passed="4" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="41">
                <test-case id="1018" name="t1_teachers_can_be_found_by_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming.t1_teachers_can_be_found_by_name" methodname="t1_teachers_can_be_found_by_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" seed="1569413628" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.016131" asserts="11" />
                <test-case id="1019" name="t2_pupils_can_be_found_by_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming.t2_pupils_can_be_found_by_name" methodname="t2_pupils_can_be_found_by_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" seed="1146943241" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.003300" asserts="11" />
                <test-case id="1020" name="t3_classrooms_can_be_found_by_name" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming.t3_classrooms_can_be_found_by_name" methodname="t3_classrooms_can_be_found_by_name" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" seed="1350320885" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.001308" asserts="11" />
                <test-case id="1021" name="t4_classrooms_can_be_renamed" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming.t4_classrooms_can_be_renamed" methodname="t4_classrooms_can_be_renamed" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T2SchoolObjectsNaming" runstate="Runnable" seed="2075361146" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.024041" asserts="8" />
              </test-suite>
              <test-suite type="TestFixture" id="1022" name="T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" testcasecount="4" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.045094" total="4" passed="4" failed="0" warnings="0" inconclusive="0" skipped="0" asserts="19">
                <test-case id="1023" name="t1_teachers_can_be_assigned_to_a_classroom" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation.t1_teachers_can_be_assigned_to_a_classroom" methodname="t1_teachers_can_be_assigned_to_a_classroom" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" seed="1473089842" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.000702" asserts="5" />
                <test-case id="1024" name="t2_when_a_teacher_is_assigned_to_a_classroom_he_losts_its_previous_classroom" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation.t2_when_a_teacher_is_assigned_to_a_classroom_he_losts_its_previous_classroom" methodname="t2_when_a_teacher_is_assigned_to_a_classroom_he_losts_its_previous_classroom" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" seed="329699032" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.000359" asserts="6" />
                <test-case id="1025" name="t3_teachers_and_classrooms_must_belong_to_the_same_school" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation.t3_teachers_and_classrooms_must_belong_to_the_same_school" methodname="t3_teachers_and_classrooms_must_belong_to_the_same_school" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" seed="556737192" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.043239" asserts="3" />
                <test-case id="1026" name="t4_assigning_a_teacher_to_a_null_classroom_removes_its_assignment" fullname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation.t4_assigning_a_teacher_to_a_null_classroom_removes_its_assignment" methodname="t4_assigning_a_teacher_to_a_null_classroom_removes_its_assignment" classname="ITI.PrimarySchool.Tests.T3TeacherClassroomAssignation" runstate="Runnable" seed="967137718" result="Passed" start-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" end-time="2018-06-26 14:55:21Z" duration="0.000626" asserts="5" />
              </test-suite>
            </test-suite>
          </test-suite>
        </test-suite>
      </test-suite>
    </test-run>';
```

--the query will read **any node, whereever it is placed** and check if there is one of the attributes you are looking for. The returned list offers info on the node itself, its parent node and the values you need:

```sql
    SELECT A.n.value('local-name(..)','nvarchar(max)') AS ParentName
          ,A.n.value('../@type','nvarchar(max)') AS ParentType
          ,A.n.value('../@id','nvarchar(max)') AS ParentID
          ,A.n.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
          ,A.n.value('@type','nvarchar(max)') AS LocalType
          ,A.n.value('@id','nvarchar(max)') AS LocalID
          ,A.n.value('./@fullname','nvarchar(max)') AS fullname
          ,A.n.value('./@passed','nvarchar(max)') AS passed
    FROM @xml.nodes('//*[not(empty(@fullname)) or not(empty(@passed))]') A(n)
```

Try it out!